# Sound Analysis Libraries?

Tags: c++, c, api, audio

I'm interested in learning about audio visualization with shaders. I want to make an application that can do visualizations from audio.

I'm looking for a library that can give me data about the audio that might be useful for visualization.Is anyone aware of any c / c++ libraries that can give me this kind of information? (Maybe the peaks and troughs, or frequencies, etc).

Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific platform you're working on?

Comment: Ideally, I would prefer if this was cross platform. My gfx api is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use FMOD Library

[The FMOD Library Link](http://www.fmod.org/)

Using this, see if [this](http://www.hiddenelephant.com/blog/2010/11/09/visualizing-music-with-fmod-and-opengl/) can be implemented

Comment: Nice one..  does it work with 64bit?

Comment: Yup, its even used by professional game developers :)